# I want to escalate the conversation to the agent portal i.e. Dynamaics omnichannel customer service. But I didn't get the response from agent portal

Tags: dynamics-365

Actually, I have built a bot and registered it with the azure service and Dynamics 365 omnichannel customer service. I want to escalate the conversation to the human agent from dynamics omnichannel customer service. I have a code snippet from Microsoft but that is in C#. I have written the logic according to the reference code in JavaScript but I didn't get a response from the agent side. Below is the C# code snippet but I want it in JavaScript. can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
 if (turnContext.Activity.Text.Contains("agent") | conversation.EscalationDictionary.ContainsKey(turnContext.Activity.Text))
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> endConversationContext = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                if (conversation.EscalationDictionary.ContainsKey(turnContext.Activity.Text)) { endConversationContext = conversation.EscalationDictionary[turnContext.Activity.Text]; }

                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Transferring  to an agent, who can help you with this. Please remain online…");

                Dictionary<string, object> handOffContext = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { "BotHandoffContext", "Specialist request" },
                    { "skill", "service" }
                };

                var handoffevent = EventFactory.CreateHandoffInitiation(turnContext, new
                {
                    MessageToAgent = "Issue Summary: billing question",
                    Context = handOffContext
                }); // Transcript is persisted by Omnichannel

                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(handoffevent);
            }
```

this is a JavaScript code that I have written. But I didn't get a response from agent portal end.

```
async function handoffMiddleware(context, next) {
    if (context.activity.text == "agent") {
        await context.sendActivity("Transferring conversation to the agent")
        //    let activities = GetRecentActivities()
        let handoffContext = {
            botHandoffContext: "specialist request",
        }
        console.log(handoffContext)
        let handoffEvent = EventFactory.createHandoffInitiation(context, {
            message: "summary:fine",
            context: handoffContext,
        })
        handoffEvent.type = ActivityTypes.Message
        handoffEvent.text = "agent can handle this issue"
        console.log(handoffEvent)
        await context.sendActivity(handoffEvent)
    }
    await next()
}
```

Comment: Did you build the bot using PVA?

Comment: No, I'm using Bot Framework